# Are addListener and addEventListener the same? Can I use them interchangeably?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Started to learn Node.js, it seems like sometimes `addListener` is used and sometimes `addEventListener`, are they completely same? Can I use any at any time?

Comment: Are you talking about solely Node.js development or are you including DOM events too?

Comment: Only for Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they aren't, and no, you can't.

What methods an API makes available will depend on the particular API.

I'm not aware of any that support `addListener` as an alias for `addEventListener` or vice versa.